# Fatal error: No such file or directory - Windows 7 64-bit Qt cross-compile for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2

I´m trying to cross-compile Qt 5.5.0 for the Raspberry Pi 2 following this tutorial: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/

On windows7 32-bit everything worked fine, but trying to build qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0 on a 64-bit system leads to the following error during "make".

> In file included from
>   C:/Users/User/Documents/Raspberry/Resources/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/platformsupport/eglconvenience/qeglplatformwindow.cpp:35:0:
>   C:/Users/User/Documents/Raspberry/Resources/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/include/QPlatformSupport/5.5.0/QtPlatformSupport/private/qopenglcompositor_p.h:1:87:
>   fatal error:
>   ../../../../../src/platformsupport/platformcompositor/qopenglcompositor_p.h:
>   No such file or directory     #include
>   "../../../../../src/platformsupport/platformcompositor/qopenglcompositor_p.h"
>   ^     compilation terminated.

The relative path is correct, but still the respective file isn´t found. Changing the content of qopenqlcompositor_p.h and replacing the relative path with an absolute path like "#include "C:/Users/Users/Documents/Raspberry/Resources/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0-new/qtbase/src/platformsupport/platformcompositor" solves the problem at first, but in the next run "make" terminates due to another fatal error which refers to a different include file that also contains a relative path.

I run configure with the following arguments:

> -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot
>   C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5
>   -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -qt-xcb
>   -qt-xkbcommon -xkb-config-root C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/share/X11/xkb -qpa
>   xcb

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Update: I meanwhile managed to build qt 5.5 after going through all include files and replacing the relative paths with the correct absolute path.

Comment: Additionally I shortened my paths building qt in C:/qt-5.5.0, because after changing the include expressions "make" terminated with another error `Assembler messages: Fatal error: can´t create .obj/Users/User/Documents/Raspberry/Resources/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libwebp/src/dec/alpha.obj: No such file or directory` `C:/Users/Users/Documents/Raspberry/Resources/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/libwebp/src/dec/alpha.c:165:1: fatal error: error writing to -: No error }^ compilation terminated.`

Comment: I would be glad if anyone knew an easier solution.